# Rotativa PDF authorization issues for header and footer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I have created a PDF through Rotativa, I need dynamic header and footer on it for every page. So I have used views as to display both header and footer.

Below is the code:-

```
string customswitch = string.Format("--allow {0} --footer-html {0} --allow {1} --header-html {1}",
                    Url.Action("Footer", "Home", new { area = "" }, "http"), Url.Action("Header", "Home", new { area = "" }, "http"));
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Footer()
    {

        return View();
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Header()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

It is working well locally, but after deployment. I can't see header and footer. I'm using windows authentication on IIS, I can only see HEADER and FOOTER on server if I enable Anonymous authentication which I don't want to.
Can you please suggest any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
foreach (var key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
            {

                CookieCollection.Add(key, Request.Cookies.Get(key).Value);
            }

return new ViewAsPdf(viewName, model)
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    CustomSwitches = customSwitches,
                    Cookies = CookieCollection,                    
                };
```